# Getting image thumbnail from img src in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, image

I'm passing a string to my controller that has the image src bytes

ex.

> src = "data:image/png;base64, sdjsdfojsdf;l";

and in c# I have a method that gets a thumbnail from a byte []

```
public static byte[] CreateImageThumbnail(byte[] image, int width, int height)
{
    using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(image))
    {
        var img = Image.FromStream(stream);
        var thumbnail = img.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);

        using (var thumbStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            thumbnail.Save(thumbStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return thumbStream.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
}
```

but now I want to be able to pass in the src string in the example above and then return a new src string as the compressed thumbnail.

ex.

```
public static string CreateImageThumbnail(string src, int width, int height)
```

What type of conversions do I need to do before and or after the 'CreateImageThumbnail' method to either pass in the src string or convert the src string to a byte array before and after the method?

Comment: How are you passing this string? Are you passing it as an Action to a Controller? Are you using a GET or POST method?

Comment: POST method a I have a string in the viewmodel that represents the string, I'm sure there's a better way so please inform me if so

Comment: you should be able to convert from base64 to binary and back again. There are already methods written to do it. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+base64+to+byte+array&oq=C%23+base64+to+&aqs=chrome.3.0j69i58j69i57j0l3.5224j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: will I have to strip out the 'data:image/png;base64' part of the string before I convert?

Comment: stripping that out makes me a little nervous, is there a better way or a more robust way?

Comment: why don't you read the docs and examples and find out? Or just try and see what happens? if you need to strip it, it's easy since it's an identical fixed length string every time, you can just trim it from the string, it's trivial. What's to be nervous about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input string and the output string should be in the exact format `"data:image/png;base64,<base64encoding>"` then we can easily extract the base 64 encoding, then convert to a byte array, then use your existing method to compress it, then convert back.

```
public static string CreateImageThumbnail(string src, int width, int height)
{
    if(src == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(src));
    string base64Start = "data:image/png;base64,";
    if(!src.StartsWith(base64Start)) throw new ArgumentException("wrong format", nameof(src));

    string base64Input  = src.Substring(base64Start.Length).Trim();
    byte[] imageData    = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Input);
    byte[] outputData   = CreateImageThumbnail(imageData);
    string base64Output = Convert.ToBase64String(outputData);

    return base64Start + base64Output;
}
```

In addition to that, you should use the `MemoryStream.ToArray()` method instead of the `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` method, as per the remarks in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks):

> Note that the buffer contains allocated bytes which might be unused. For example, if the string "test" is written into the MemoryStream object, the length of the buffer returned from GetBuffer is 256, not 4, with 252 bytes unused. To obtain only the data in the buffer, use the ToArray method; however, ToArray creates a copy of the data in memory.

so your original code for getting the thumbnail of a byte array image data should be

```
public static byte[] CreateImageThumbnail(byte[] image, int width, int height)
{
    using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(image))
    {
        var img = Image.FromStream(stream);
        var thumbnail = img.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);

        using (var thumbStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            thumbnail.Save(thumbStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return thumbStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

### Edit

Since you need to be able to work with all formats of the form `"data:<mimetype>;base64,<base64encoding>"`, and base64 encoded strings do not contain the character ',', and neither do mime types. So we can use `string.Split()` to get the base64 encoded data.

```
public static string CreateImageThumbnail(string src, int width, int height)
{
    if(src == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(src));
    string[] split = src.Split(',');
    if(split.Length != 2) throw new ArgumentException("wrong format", nameof(src));
    string base64Start  = split[0] + ",";
    string base64Input  = split[1].Trim();
    byte[] imageData    = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Input);
    byte[] outputData   = CreateImageThumbnail(imageData);
    string base64Output = Convert.ToBase64String(outputData);

    return base64Start + base64Output;
}
```

Comment: I can't use a hard coded string here because the img might be a png or a gif or jpg or some other img type

Comment: @user1186050 I've edited my answer to answer your concern. in short: use `string.Split` to get the header and data.

Answer (score 0):

```
  using System;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


        // source element
         var ImageLink = "<img src='http://nydomain.com/Image.jpg' />";

        // pattern to extract image source
         string ImageSrc = Regex.Match(ImageLink, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].+?>", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;

        // showing output here
        Console.WriteLine(ImageSrc);
```